# Select CSS nested class having a certain class above

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply some style to the tag with "target-class" ONLY when there is another tag with "source-class" ABOVE it. So it can be either at the same level, which can be easily solved by `.source-class ~ .target-class`, or inside some parent class(es), like:

```
<div class="source-class">class to look for</div>
<div class="parent-class">
    <div class="target-class">class to apply</div>
</div>
```

but does not need to check inside another tag, like:

```
<div>
    <div class="source-class"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent-class">
    <div class="target-class">nothing to apply</div>
</div>
```

How would you write such CSS selector? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.source-class ~ .target-class,
.source-class ~ * > .target-class
{
  /* your style here */
}
```

If you want unlimited children levels, just remove `>`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!